# Moq call returning empty when setup to return dummy data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ninject, moq

I'm hung up when specifying mock data to be returned from a mocked repository. My test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAllImports_SomeImportRecordsExist_ReturnsNonEmptyList() {
    // Arrange
    var repo = new Mock<IImportRepository>();
    repo.Setup(import => import.GetAll()).Returns(new[] {new Import()});

    var manager = new ImportConfigurationManager(repo.Object);

    // Act
    var result = manager.GetAllImports();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof (IList<Import>));
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
}
```

The last assert fails as the manager under test returns an empty list. The manager:

```
public class ImportConfigurationManager : IImportConfigurationManager
{
    private readonly IImportRepository _importRepository;

    public ImportConfigurationManager(IImportRepository repository)
    {
        _importRepository = repository;
    }

    public IList<Import> GetAllImports() {
        return _importRepository.GetAll(import => import) ?? new Import[0];
    }
}
```

I have stepped through the test and watched the manager call to GetAll return null, so I believe that my error lies in setting up the mock repository instance. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

Patrick pointed out that I was calling GetAll differently in my manager and test. Making the calls consistent (in either direction) solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there's two versions of `IImportRepository.GetAll()`, one that takes no argument (referenced in your mock setup) and one that takes a lambda (used in the manager).  Is that the issue?

Comment: @spock, having done more testing I now also use the 'is any' style parameter when my test can is unconcerned with parameters. Patrick did catch my issue, but I agree with your setup, marked as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below might help. I get a list of imports. Return a List in your setup and make sure the Func has setup correctly.

```
    public class ImportConfigurationManager : IImportConfigurationManager
    {
        private readonly IImportRepository _importRepository;

        public ImportConfigurationManager(IImportRepository repository)
        {
            _importRepository = repository;
        }

        public IList<Import> GetAllImports()
        {
            var imports = _importRepository.GetAll(import => import) ?? new Import[0];
            return imports;
        }
    }

    public interface IImportRepository
    {
        IList<Import> GetAll(Func<object, object> func);
    }

    public interface IImportConfigurationManager
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllImports_SomeImportRecordsExist_ReturnsNonEmptyList()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repo = new Mock<IImportRepository>();
        repo.Setup(import => import.GetAll(It.IsAny<Func<object, object>>())).Returns(new List<Import>(){new Import()});

        var manager = new ImportConfigurationManager(repo.Object);

        // Act
        var result = manager.GetAllImports();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IList<Import>));
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
    }
```